# Linear navigation in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view

I'm using the Cinch MVVM framework, however I think this is something that relates to all WPF approaches.

I want to have a primary screen - Shell or MainWindow - which then contains various viewmodels. To navigate between viewmodels I'm using (or going to use) a tab control styled as a button strip with the content area beneath - which is all ok as I add the viewmodels to the tabcontrol (well to the 'Views' collection which is bound to the tab control) at runtime.

A screen that doesn't fit into this methodology is the sign in screen, which I don't really want to add to the tab control - preferably it should be in it's own usercontrol which takes up the entire screen apart from covering the logo; that is, I would like it to appear in the same window rather than a popup dialog, however I'm not sure how to add/ remove controls dynamically and then add subsequent tabcontrol once the user has signed in successfully (and remove the sign in screen). What containers should be used?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is put your tabcontrol in a Grid without columns and rows so it fill the grid by default. Then add an extra grid or loginusercontrol to the grid as shown below. The moment a user needs to login you can set the visibility of the MainTabControl" to collapsed and of the LoginGrid to Visible and switch it back after a succesfull login. I hope that the xaml below will help you enough.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" Visiblity="Visible">
        ... put your tabs here ...
    </TabControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LoginGrid" Background="#60FFFFFF" Visibility="Collapsed">
        ... put your usercontrol to login here or the login controls themself
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I'll give this one a go I think, and use the VisualStateManager in Cinch to switch visibility between the two. thanks.

Comment: The use of the VisualStateManager to set these states is a very good idea, perhaps with using the GoToStateBehavior

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ContentControl with content bound to a view model. So you'd have two view-models representing the sign-in screen and the main screen and use DataTemplate to display appropriate screen.

```
<Window.Resources>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my_view_models:SignInViewModel}">
  <my_controls:SignInScreenView />
</DataTemplate>
...
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Content={Binding} />
```

Comment: With Cinch stuff it's done on a View first basis, and so the viewmodel is injected using MEF at runtime. I'm sure this would work with other approaches though.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested by [Lakana](http://lakana.codeplex.com), it is a lightweight and non intrusive navigation framework for WPF.

Riana